# Apache Spark: ERROR local class incompatible when initiating a SparkContext class

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, version

Hi I'm runnign example on Spark site at http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications

spark version: spark-1.4.0

sbt version: 0.13.8

And I ran command "sbt run" and got error "**java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.deploy.ApplicationDescription; local class incompatible**".

This application fails at "val sc = new SparkContext(conf)", when I'm trying to initiate a SparkContext class. I've googled around and see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682836/standalone-spark-cluster-cant-submit-job-programmatically-java-io-invalidcl) but I didn't use hadoop-client.

Could you please check it out? My guess is a version issue in build.sbt. Thank you very much.

**update**: I've try to submit python application and works fine which means Spark cluster is OK.

scala code is below:

```
/* SimpleApp.scala */
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "YOUR_SPARK_HOME/README.md" // Should be some file on your system
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
  }
}
```

**built.sbt** is below:

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"
```

error message is below:

```
15/08/27 05:23:38 ERROR Remoting: org.apache.spark.deploy.ApplicationDescription; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7674242335164700840, local class serialVersionUID = -7685200927816255400
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.deploy.ApplicationDescription; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7674242335164700840, local class serialVersionUID = -7685200927816255400
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$1.apply(Serializer.scala:136)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer.fromBinary(Serializer.scala:136)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(Serialization.scala:104)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:98)
    at akka.remote.serialization.MessageContainerSerializer.fromBinary(MessageContainerSerializer.scala:63)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(Serialization.scala:104)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:98)
    at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.deserialize(MessageSerializer.scala:23)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$lzycompute$1(Endpoint.scala:58)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$1(Endpoint.scala:58)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.dispatch(Endpoint.scala:76)
    at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:937)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:415)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You say you are running with a Spark 1.4.0 cluster but your `build.sbt` is building with 1.2.0.  Please change to this in your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.0"
```